# Showing live CPU usage via WMI with PHP and Ajax

Tags: php, laravel, wmi

Is there any alternative to a persistent connection with **just** Apache/PHP than setting up another server with WebSockets/Node.js?

At the current moment, I'm running a typical WAMP server with a Laravel application. This laravel application is a sort of dashboard app which can show details (such as CPU/Network usage) of our servers on the network. This application will only be used by a couple of people at a time (it's internal) so it allows me to be quite flexible with performance.

I'm using the COM library in PHP to query the server for information via WMI. I have it set up by using a typical GET route that returns a json string of the CPU usage in percentage of the server from WMI. This is getting refreshed every single second using `setInterval()`.

Though obviously this is immense load on the server, and CPU goes through the roof when seeing the usage of a network PC.

A picture is below showing what my app looks like. The progress bar will fill to the percentage returned when the ajax request completes. It looks good and works well, but I feel like running an ajax request every single second is bad design, and really want something that can just constantly feed the progress bar rather than request a new value from the server.

Please let me know if you need any code/examples of my current progress. Thanks!

Code as requested:

My route:

`Route::get('{machine_id}/{field?}', array('as'=>'admin.computer.view.detailed', 'uses'=>'ComputerController@getViewDetailed'));`

My Controller:

```
public function getViewDetailed($computer_id, $field = NULL){
    $computer = $this->machine->find($computer_id);

    if($computer){
        if(!$computer->type->type_name == 'Servers'){
            return Redirect::route('admin.computer.index');
        } else{
            if($field){
                switch($field){
                    case 'cpu':
                        return Response::json(Network::get_cpu_info($computer->machine_name));
                        break;
                    case 'temp':
                        return Response::json(Network::get_temp_info($computer->machine_name));
                        break;
                    case 'tcp':
                        return Response::json(Network::get_tcp_info($computer->machine_name));
                        break;
                }
            }
            $disks  = Network::get_disk_info($computer->machine_name);
            $memory = Network::get_memory_info($computer->machine_name);
            $cpu    = Network::get_cpu_info($computer->machine_name);
            $tcp    = Network::get_tcp_info($computer->machine_name);

            $this->layout->title = 'Viewing Server Details for: '.$computer->machine_name;
            $this->layout->content = View::make('computers.templates.view.detailed')
                ->with('computer', $computer)
                ->with('disks', $disks)
                ->with('memory', $memory)
                ->with('cpu', $cpu)
                ->with('tcp', $tcp);
        }
    } else{
        return Redirect::route('admin.computer.index')
            ->with('message', Lang::get('custom.messages.computers.errors.exist'))
            ->with('color','danger');
    }
}
```

My class requesting WMI Information:

```
class Cpu {

public static $com_namespace = 'root\\cimv2';
private $query = 'SELECT Name, CurrentClockSpeed, LoadPercentage From Win32_Processor';

private $cpu = array();

public function info($service, $pc){
    $this->cpu = $service->ExecQuery($this->query);
    return $this->format($this->cpu);
}

public function format($cpu){
    $formatted_cpu = array();

    $i = 0;
    foreach($cpu as $entry){
        $formatted_cpu[$i]['name'] = $entry->Name;
        $formatted_cpu[$i]['current_clock_speed'] = $entry->CurrentClockSpeed;
        $formatted_cpu[$i]['load'] = $entry->LoadPercentage;
        $i++;
    }

    return $formatted_cpu;
}
}
```

My View:

```
@if($cpu)
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        function getCpu(){
            $('.server').each(function(index, element) {
                var server = $(this);
                var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
                var panel = $(this).find('.panel');
                var progress_bar = $(this).find('.progress-bar');

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType:"json",
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response){
                            $(progress_bar).html(response[0]['load']+"%").attr('aria-valuenow', response[0]['load']).css('width', response[0]['load']+"%");

                            if(response[0]['load'] > 50){
                                $(panel).removeClass('panel-default').addClass('panel-danger');
                            } else{
                                $(panel).removeClass('panel-danger').addClass('panel-default');
                            }
                        } else{
                            $(server).css('display', 'none');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        }

        setInterval(getCpu, 1000);
    });
</script>

<div data-url="{{ route('admin.computer.view.detailed', array($computer->id, 'cpu')) }}" class="server">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">CPU Load</div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: "*need any code/examples of my current progress.*" .. yep

Comment: Try looking at http://reactphp.org/

Comment: Thanks @TheShiftExchange! I'm going to try that out now. Also @Kermit, I'll be posting my code soon